# HaProxy - Direct to backend server according to query string

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I am using HaProxy to load balance between my 2 servers. My mobile app connects to one of this 2 servers directed by the loadbalancer. My apps mainly makes this http request to loadbalancer:

http://www.example.com/file.php?action=getdata

and this is being redirected to one of these 2 servers and there is no problem with this but I need this requests to direct to server2 always because these specific actions are stored on the database of server2.

http://www.example.com/file.php?action=gettoken OR
http://www.example.com/file.php?action=savetoken

How can I achieve this with haproxy's config file ? Currently it looks like:

```
frontend haproxynode
bind *:80
mode http
default_backend backendnodes
backend backendnodes
balance roundrobin
option forwardfor
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
server node1 ip:80 check
server node2 ip:80 check
```

Comment: Edit: I found a solution to my own question: We have to use url_sub to find a string in the url and if it is exists , you have to use acl to direct the traffic to server

Answer (score 1):

```
use server node2 if { url_param(action) -m str gettoken } || { url_param(action) -m str savetoken }
```

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-url_param

Using `url_sub` is a little bit sloppy, since it examines the entire query string.